# How to play a system sound in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for lightweight built in system cross platform sound player. Something that could beep like [System.Console.Beep](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Console/) and which i could invoke directly from my view model.

I'm aware that i could use a provider (strategy) pattern to coin the platform specific implementations or to use some media player like [XamarinMediaManager](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dependency service

**ANDROID**

```
public class AudioService : IAudio
{

    private MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;

    public bool PlayFile()
    {
        _mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(global::Android.App.Application.Context, Resource.Raw.test);
        _mediaPlayer.Start();

        return true;
    }

}
```

**IOS**

```
public class AudioService : IAudio
{

private AVAudioPlayer _ringtoneAudioPlayer;
public AudioService()
{
    _ringtoneAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename("call.caf"));
    _ringtoneAudioPlayer.NumberOfLoops = -1; // infinite
}

public void PlayFile()
{
    if (_ringtoneAudioPlayer != null)
    {
        _ringtoneAudioPlayer.Stop();
    }
    _ringtoneAudioPlayer.Play();
}
}
```

**UWP**

```
public class AudioService : IAudio
{

    public async Task PlayAudioUWP(string fileName)
    {
        StorageFolder Folder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
        StorageFile sf = await Folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
        var PlayMusic = new MediaElement();
        PlayMusic.AudioCategory = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AudioCategory.Media;
        PlayMusic.SetSource(await sf.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read), sf.ContentType);
        PlayMusic.Play();
    }

}
```

If you want you can try and this plugin

https://www.nuget.org/packages/XamarinAudioManager/

Comment: Thanks. In my question i'm asking for built in system cross platform way to play simple sounds. Could you add UWP platform as well, so you answer is more complete and useful?