# How to play a system sound in MAUI or how to Debug MAUI Release Build on Android emulator

Tags: maui

I am developing an app in MAUI. It works well in Debug Mode, but not at all in Release Mode on the simulators or on physical phone. I have tried what I found on Stackoverflow, that is  adding [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)] to the MainPage class and disabling ahead-of-time compilation. This helped in so far as now the Release build runs on Windows (which it didn't before), but didn't help for the Android Release build.

I now want to debug this by beep-debugging. Therefore I would need a simple and reliable way to make the simulator or physical device beep. Like System.Console.Beep(). System.Console.Beep() works in the Windows Machine, but makes the app crash immediately in the Simulator, even in Debug build.
I only found [How to play a system sound in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185359/how-to-play-a-system-sound-in-xamarin-forms), but that question is 6 years old, about Xamarin and has no accepted answer.
I just want a beep, nothing fancy.

Comment: Wouldn’t writing to the log be a lot more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to beep, but I found a better way to debug Release build on Android Emulator. It is: Run "Tools > Android > Device Log" in VS.

BTW, the problem causing the crash in Release build
was just some strings in a picker, like this:

```
<Picker x:Name="p" SelectedIndexChanged="pSelectedIndexChanged">
    <Picker.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>Apple</x:String>
            <x:String>Banana</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Picker.ItemsSource>
</Picker>
```

The log told me that the XAML Parser on Android doesn't know the type String. Worked perfectly in Debug build. Removing the Picker fixed the crash.

Comment: 1. As Jason suggested it would be more efficient if write to the log than beep-debugging. 2. You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.